# Could not find 'nvcuda.dll' TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I have sucessfully gone through installing

- CUDA 9.0,
- cuDNN v6.0 Library for Windows 10.(for CUDA 9.0),
- Anaconda 3.5,
- Updated Conda

  and Sucessfully followed https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Copied cudnn64_7.dll from cudnn to bin of NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit.

Added C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\ to path variable.

But while doing **import tensorflow as tf**,

ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'.

Please help..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRT7J.png

Comment: do you have a NVIDIA GPU in your machine?  If so, which driver version is installed (`nvcuda.dll` is provided by the driver)?  Perhaps you can use the windows file find utility to locate where `nvcuda.dll` is on your machine.

Comment: You appear to have a 32 bit Python installation.